# How fast must a CF be to save 2560x1920 TIFF?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, memory-card, compactflash

I have an [Olympus E-20P](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/olympuse20/) which is 10 years old with a 256MB CompactFlash card.

It won't let me choose 2560x1920 TIFF, so I assume that my CompactFlash isn't fast enough.

Are there any rule of thumbs for what speed is needed to save 2560x1920?

**Update**

According to the manual:

- RAW, 2560x1920, ~10MB
- TIFF, 2560x1920, ~15MB
- SHQ, 2560x1920, ~3.9MB
- HQ, 2560x1920, ~1.5MB

When the camera is powered on it selects HQ, and even if I choose TIFF, it won't change.

So I suspect that it is my "Sandisk CF SDCFB-256" with 3.6MB/s that is the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't this be in the camera manual?  What makes you think it's not allow the high res mode due to flash card speed?

Comment: It is very sparse on this subject, but I have updated the post with  the supported formats and my CF specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to notice this from the [FAQ](http://www.olympusamerica.com/files/e20_faq10.pdf) I referenced in the answer to your [last question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18214/can-an-olympus-e20p-take-8gb-flash-cards):

> Question:
>   If I purchase a high performance CompactFlash card for my E-10/20N, will it reduce the time
>   writing to the media.
>
> Answer:
>   No, the writing time is controlled by the camera, not by the Media.

In other words, it won't help.

(This mentions the "N" version, but as I understand it the only difference is video out format, NTSC vs. PAL.)

And [this review](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/E20/E20A10.HTM) say that this camera can *only* save TIFF in 2560 × 1920 — so *something else is going on*.

Comment: I guess that explains why I don't see the RAW option despite the manual lists RAW as an option. But VERY nice to have it cleared that it ought to be able to save TIFF with my current CF.

Comment: Knowing that the CF supports TIFF and RAW I now figured out how to save in both formats. I had to hold down a button and turn a wheel instead of selecting TIFF from the LED display. Go figure =)